# Rails mountable engine: how should apps set configuration variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I have a mountable engine called `Blog` that apps can use.

What's the best way to allow apps that use the engine to set a configuration variable like `site_name` (so that the engine can display it in the design)?

**Update:**

I've seen some gems create a 'config/initializers/gem_name.rb' file. Is there any specification on how to:

1. Create a file like that on the engine's side
2. Copy it into the app's side
3. How to access those set variables on the engine's side?

I tried creating `Blog.site_name = "My Site"` in the app's `config/initializers/blog.rb` file but get an Undefined method error.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Figured out an even better solution that also allows you to set default values (incase the app using the engine doesn't specify a config)...

1. Create config variables in your app's `/config/initializers/blog.rb` like this:

```
    Blog.setup do |config|
        config.site_name = "My Site Name"
    end
```

2. In your engine's `/lib/blog/engine.rb` set default values like this:

```
    module Blog
    
         self.mattr_accessor :site_name
         self.site_name = "Site Name"
         # add default values of more config vars here
    
         # this function maps the vars from your app into your engine
         def self.setup(&block)
            yield self
         end
    
    end
```

3. Now you can simply access the config variables in your engine like this:

`Blog.site_name`

Much cleaner.

Comment: If you are using the `yield` keyword, assigning the &block variable is not necessary. You can simply use `def self.setup` instead.

Comment: In rails 4 / ruby 2 I had to use **Blog::Engine.site_name** since after `module Blog` you have a `class Engine < ::Rails::Engine`

Comment: Skip the `setup` method definition and `alias_method :setup :tap`. It's an identical method signature

Comment: The original answer didn't work with Rails 6.1. It would produce an error `TypeError: module attributes should be defined directly on class, not singleton` as reported at https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/40831. I have edited the answer to make it work also with Rails 6.1, but to keep trace, before `mattr_accessor :site_name` it had  `class << self` and after the comment  `# add default values of more config vars here` it had `end`

Answer (score 6):

After a lot of testing and looking into existing gems, here is what works in Rails 4:

Considering your engine's name is `Blog`:

In your engine's `/lib/blog/engine.rb` put in this:

```
module Blog

    def self.setup(&block)
        @config ||= Blog::Engine::Configuration.new

        yield @config if block

        @config
    end

    def self.config
        Rails.application.config
    end

end
```

In your app, create a file called `/config/initalizers/blog.rb` and set config vars like this:

```
Blog.setup do |config|
    config.testingvar = "asdfasdf"
end
```

Then you can access these config variables ANYWHERE in your engine like this:

`Blog.config.testingvar`

Hope this helps someone. There is very little documentation on this right now so it was all trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a fairly old post, but in the event someone in the future finds this, I'd like to recommend the [Angostura gem](https://github.com/justindoody/angostura) for passing dependencies into a Rails engine. To use it, assuming my engine is called 'Blog' and I want to access a variable called 'site_name', the engine's `lib/blog.rb` looks something like:

```ruby
require "blog/engine"
require "angostura"

module Blog
  include Angostura::Dependencies

  dependency :site_name
end
```

In my main app, in `config/initializers/blog.rb`, I added

```ruby
Blog.setup do |config|
  config.site_name = "My site name"
end
```

Now, I can access `site_name` in my engine by calling `Blog.site_name`.

I'd like to point out that defaults are also supported, so you could do something like `dependency site_name: 'Default site name'` in `lib/blog.rb`. Furthermore, you can pass in whole classes as dependencies by sending it stringified classnames, like `config.my_class = 'MyClass'`.

For posterity, in order to use the gem, I added `s.add_dependency "angostura", "0.6.0"` in my engine's gemspec, and then ran `bundle install`.